# How do I substract a number from an entire integer column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have a table (Sales) with a column (Number) that contains integers, for example 22000001, 22000002 etc.. Now I want to permanently edit the records by substracting 1.000.000 from that number for every row in the table, so that it will be 21000001, 21000002, etc..

I tried: `SELECT Number -= 1000000 FROM Sales;` This only gives me a syntax error.

Comment: I want to modify the records permanently. I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the records permanently, you'll need to use an [`UPDATE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of a `SELECT` statement (query).

The statement takes the form:

```sql
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column 1] = [Value 1], [Column 2] = [Value 2] WHERE [Some Condition]
```

Your `[Table]` is "Sales", your `[Column 1]` is "Number", `[Value 1]` is the original value minus 1000000, and you're modifying every row in the table so you don't need `[Some Condition]`.

Your resulting query should be:

```sql
UPDATE Sales SET Number = Number - 1000000
```